# C programming gdb error message

Tags: c, gdb

I am new to using gdb so I wanted to start by using a simple program that prints "Hello"

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

saving as hello.c and then typing gdb. Once opened, based from tutorials, I type "file hello.c" in order to load the program into the debugger, but I get this message:

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
"hello.c": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

So I typed in the "gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello" and got this message:

```
hello.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to âintâ [-Wreturn-type] hello.c: 
In function âmainâ: hello.c:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

so then I edited main with int main and added return 0 in the code. I did it again, no errors so I typed gdb ./hello and it worked...should I always have my mains as int main with the return 0 included?

Comment: You debug compiled executables, not source code.

Comment: Your program is incorrect. Declare main as `int main()` or preferably `int main (int argc, char**argv)`

Comment: And don't forget the `return 0;` before the closing brace `}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the packaged (for your system) `gdb` debugger and `gcc` compiler. On Debian and related (e.g. Ubuntu) distributions, run as root (e.g. with `sudo`):

```
 apt-get install gcc gdb build-essential
```

On Linux, you need (or want) to compile your `hello.c` with all warnings and debug info, i.e. using

```
 gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello
```

At that point you could get some error or warning messages from `gcc`; try to correct your source file `hello.c` and repeat the compilation again.

<sup>You should decide to use the [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard, then add `-std=c99` after `gcc` and before `-Wall`</sup>

Check with

```
 ls -ls hello.c hello
```

that your `hello` executable has been generated (and is younger than the source `hello.c` file).

Then you start the debugger (by giving the debuggable executable) as

```
 gdb ./hello
```

You then get a `(gdb)` prompt. Try to put a breakpoint in `main` using the

```
 break main
```

GDB command. Then, run your program with `run`, it should reach the breakpoint at `main`; at that point, type `help` to get some help about GDB commands.

<sup>Most GDB commands can be abbreviated with their first few letters. So you could type `b` instead of `break`.</sup>

You definitely should learn about the `watch` gdb command, it is *extremely* useful in practice.

---

About `main` you should define it as `int main (int argc, char**argv)` and you should end it with `return 0;` (or some other small positive integer, for runtime error cases). Actually, you should add `#include <stdlib.h>` as an included header (like you do for `<stdio.h>`) and use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`. Read also about [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html); in general read the documentation of every function that you are using (e.g. [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)), and accept that you might not understand first all the documentation. You may want to install the `manpages-dev` package and learn about the `man` command.

Comment: I typed in the "gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello" and got this message: hello.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to âintâ [-Wreturn-type]
hello.c: In function âmainâ:
hello.c:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]  so then I edited main with int main and added return 0 in the code. I did it again, no errors so I typed gdb ./hello and it worked...

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it by telling the messages (in your question, not in comments)

Comment: So the compiler warns you as it should. Your `hello.c` program is wrong. But use `ls -ls hello` to check that the `hello` executable has been recently generated.

Comment: Int argc, char** argv isn't necessary for this really, as with a simple hello world console input isn't exactly required.